# Components of the Fitting Decomposition for $L$ are Invariant under $M$'s with $ad(L)^sM=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras, linear-transformations

Let $L \in End(V)$ and $V=A\oplus B$ be it's Fitting Decomposition. This means $L$ is nilpotent and invertible when restricted to $A$ and $B$ respectively. $A$ and $B$ are constructed by taking successive images and nullspaces of powers of $L$.

Let $M$ be another endomorphism of $V$ such that for some $s \in \mathbb{N}$, $ad(L)^s(M)=0$.

I want to show $A$ and $B$ are invariant under $M$.

The formula $ad(L)^s(M)=\sum_{0}^{s} {s\choose p}L^pML^{s-p}$ will probably be useful but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Can someone please show me how to proceed?

Edit: I'm reading Varadarajan's $Lie groups$, $Lie$ $Algebras$ $and$ $Representations$. There are a bunch of theorems like this which he states. Another similar theorem is that the Jordan factors of $L$ are invariant under $M$ if and only if the above condition holds.

Comment: What do you mean by $A,B$ are invariant under $M$ ? In your formula you forgot a $(-1)^ p$.

Comment: Apologies, there's a $(-1)^s$ factor as well. Invariant means $M$ sends $A$ into $A$ etc.

Comment: Part of the second question can be proved using the formula $(L-\lambda I)^nMv=\sum_{0}^{n}ad(L)^iM(L-\lambda I)^{n-i}v$. This formula can be proved by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f=ad(L)$ and $spectrum(L)=(\lambda_i)_i$. Then $ker(f^s)\subset \ker(f^{n^2})$ and we may assume that $M\in \ker(f^{n^2})$. Note that $f=L\otimes I-I\otimes L^T$ (when we stack the matrix row by row) and $spectrum(f)=\{\lambda_i-\lambda_j|1\leq i,j\leq n\}$; remark that $0$ is a semi simple eigenvalue of $f^{n^2}$.

Let $L=D+N$ where $D$ is diagonalizable, $N$ nilpotent and $DN=ND$ (Jordan-Chevalley decomposition) and let $g=ad(D)$. Using the Jordan form of $L$, it is not difficult to see that $\ker(f^{n^2})=\ker(g^{n^2})$. Since $g$ is diagonalizable, $\ker(g^{n^2})=\ker(g)$ and finally $\ker(f^{n^2})=\ker(g)$, that is $M\in \ker(f^{n^2})$ iff $DM=MD$.

Conclusion: $M\in \ker(f^{n^2})$ iff the generalized eigenspaces of $L$ (the $\ker((L-\lambda I)^n)$ when $\lambda$ runs through $spectrum(L)$) are invariant under $M$.

Comment: Will go through your answer tonight, thanks!